# Offline html5 validator

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I would like to pass a few pages of a web application we are building through an HTML5 validator.
I found several "online" validation tools available, but for privacy reasons I would rather not upload our pages for checking.

Do you know any **offline** HTML5 validation tool / library?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586207/validate-html-on-local-machine?

Comment: I believe it is now recommended by w3, but I think not even have a lib available (dtd file or something).

Comment: @net.uk.sweet not appear to be duplicates, just seems to be offtopic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download a `vnu.jar` release for checking HTML5 documents offline.
See https://github.com/validator/validator/releases/latest for the actual download file, and see https://validator.github.io/validator/ for more information

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's a matter of a one-liner to install an offline HTML5 validation tool (as requested by the OP) as of today, e.g. `pip install html5validator` (this example requires Python and Java installed), see the [documentation](https://github.com/svenkreiss/html5validator) for usage examples.

Comment: To use `vnu.jar` to validate as you type ("on the fly") in the Atom editor, use the new [`linter-vnu`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vnu) Atom package (published today).

Answer (score 1):

So far W3C has only published the DTD up to HTML 4.01.

Download libs: http://validator.w3.org/sgml-lib.tar.gz

In September 2012, the W3C proposed a [plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#Plan_2014) (wikipedia.org) to release a stable HTML5 Recommendation by the end of 2014 and an HTML 5.1 specification Recommendation by the end of 2016.

Therefore I believe that the libs for HTML5 are coming this year.

Meanwhile you can use an unofficial DTD file, available here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html5-dtd.html

Comment: @Mr.E. Thanks. +1 for you question

Comment: There is [no HTML5 DTD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4053917/2157640) and there will never be one. It’s impossible to write a DTD for HTML5, the same way it is [impossible to parse HTML via a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2157640).